# Optimization with a vector as the choice set

Tags: optimization, notation, vectors

Suppose I have a vector $s=(1,2,2,3,5)$.

I want to say: $\min_{x \in s} |2.1-x| = 0.1$.

I know this is incorrect because $s$ is not a set. Is there some notation or language such that $\text{Notation}(s)=\{1,2,3,5\}$, and I can write that $\min_{x \in \text{Notation}(s)} |2.1-x| = 0.1$?

Or am I missing an easier way to express this? Or a conceptual understanding of why I shouldn't be wanting to do this in the first place?

Comment: you can write something like min (subscript) "x is a coordinate of $s$" $|2.1-x|$

Comment: Now that I think more about it, would it work to just say $\min_i |2.1-s_i|$?

Comment: yep that's even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further reflection, $\min_i |2.1-s_i|=0.1$ communicates the desired message.